# What is the VS Code workbench.colorCustomizations code for the search result highlighting after manually highlighting the same text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the workbench color customization for the ____t in this image?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZZNQ.png)

Here is my settings.json:

```json
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Hyper Dracula",
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tab.activeBackground": "#282a36",
    "tab.border": "#282a36",
    "tab.hoverBackground": "#282a36",
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#44475a",
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#135564"
  },
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#FF9900"
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "sync.gist": "20cf55b3a5eb6aa675ee54477c73dd4d",
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "editor.rename.enablePreview": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are talking about a `const` variable name in javascript.  You can use the `Scopes` inspector from the Command Palette to see it has the scope of `variable.other.constant.js`.  You would use that in your settings like this:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": "variable.other.constant.js",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#FF0000",
        "fontStyle": "bold"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, that will change the styling of **all** `const` variable names, not just `const _______t`.  If you want to style only `const _______t` you will need to use an extension like [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) to target specific text.

In your settings:

```
"highlight.regexes": {

  "(const\\s+)(_+\\w+)(\\s*=.*)": {     // note double-escaping
    "decorations": [
      {},
      {
        "overviewRulerColor": "#ffcc00",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffcc00",
        "color": "#1f1f1f",
        "fontWeight": "bold"
      },
      {}
    ]
  }
```

would target `(_+\\w+)` - some number of underscores before a `\w` for example that follows a `const`  and precedes  `= .*` in regex terms.